# How do I submit a sitemap for URLs on a redirected domain?

Tags: redirects, sitemap

I have domain `www.example.ca` and the domain is redirected to `www.example.com`. I have sitemap in `www.example.com`.

How do I submit sitemap hosted in `www.example.com` for `www.example.ca`?

Comment: *How do I submit sitemap hosted in `www.example.com` for `www.example.ca`?* You don't. If the domain has been redirected to another, there is no purpose or way to submit a sitemap for the redirected domain. If a sitemap is requested for the redirected domain, in theory, and assuming you redirected all requests, the sitemap will be picked up from the new domain. Cheers!!